# CSS 3 PIE: Not working inside an absolutely positioned (popup) element? Shifts on mouseover?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, rounded-corners

I am using the CSS 3 PIE include so that I can have rounded borders on my popup in IE. However, in IE, the popup is not rounded on the pageload, but when I mouse over it, it shifts to the top-left corner of the container, which is positioned absolutely, and THERE it has rounded borders.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="popupWrapper" id="editMsgWrapper">
        <div class="popupDiv" id="editMsgContainer">
```

And here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.popupWrapper {
    display:none;
    left:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:601;
}

.popupDiv {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    border: none; /*1px solid #FFF;*/
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    behavior: url(PIE.php);
    position: relative;
}
```

Any idea as to why the popupDiv is shifting to the absolute div on a mouseover?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dropped it in another container div and that worked somehow!